# Suggest a Java Collection for this type of data

Tags: java, collections, datatable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [(C#) DataTable equivalent in JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340283/c-datatable-equivalent-in-java)

Hi
I want dataTable like in .Net structure to store my data(in memory obviously). what collection is suitable for this

Comment: im not familiar with .net, can you describe the dataTable?

Comment: @user616391: If you would describe what a `DataTable` in .NET does, or at least link to a documentation, even the ones who don't know .NET could suggest something.

Comment: a quick read of DataTable doc, perhaps would push one to javax.sql.rowset.WebRowSet.  http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/sql/rowset/WebRowSet.html    but i have no knowledge of this DataTable class, so...