# Is there a type in java equivalent to DataSet in C#?

Tags: java, resultset

The question is as title.
When I use ResultSet in Java, I find if the connection and PreparedStatement are closed, I Can't read any records from ResultSet.
How to keep readding the ResultSet when the connection is colsed?

Comment: I think the "closest" standard class might be the DefaultTableModel (which is hardly close at all). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340283/datatable-equivalent-in-java and similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably looking for [disconnected rowsets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/rowset.html).

But frankly, most of the time, I just transform the data in a result set into a list of Java objects, and then close the connection, and use this list of objects later on.

Comment: +1, for this _I just transform the data in a result set into a list of Java objects, and then close the connection_ :)

Comment: How do you put multiple columns' value in one object?

Comment: `object.setFoo(resultSet.getString(1)); object.setBar(resultSet.getInt(2));` etc., or, `MyObject obj = new MyObject(resultSet.getString(1), resultSet.getInt(2));`. Objects can have multiple attributes.

Comment: rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
   List<Object> l=new ArrayList<Object>() ;
   while(rs.next())
   {
    Object o=new Object();
    //write something
    l.add(o);
   }
   
   return l;  How to write in the 'while'

Comment: The list should contain instances of objects of a class *you* define, containing the appropriate attributes, constructor, methods, etc. So it should be a `List<MyObject>`, and not a `List<Object>` (MyObject just being an example name. If you're querying for users, the name of the class should probably be `User`).