# database table XML import/export (like C# DataTable)

Tags: c#, android, sqlite, datatable

I want my app to be able to communicate between a database and an XML file exactly the same as what a `DataTable` does in C#.

I found that [WebRowSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/webrowset.html) is an equivalent in Java, but it works with JDBC, not SQLite. I want to know is there any framework for that in Android?

I know I can do this operation myself but I am searching for a suitable framework.

I have seen a similar question: [DataTable equivalent in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340283/datatable-equivalent-in-java). But I need an equivalent in Android, not in Java.

Comment: @Sriram , It is not a duplicated question.

Comment: What do you mean by you need an equivalent in android? Which language you're using for android?

Comment: I am using java but the answer you mentioned uses a framework that is designed to work with JDBC library. It doesn't support Sqlite so it is not useful for android.