# Best implementation of a table in Java

Tags: java

The question is not too dificult: How do I best implement a table in Java.

I wish to have something like a table in a database. Named columns and numbered rows. My values are `Integer`.

My inital idea: `LinkedHashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>>`

But is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: ...considered using a real database? SQLite is fantastically easy to use if you just need a simple database.

Comment: Why `LinkedHashMap` instead of `HashMap`? You don't need to ensure the order.

Comment: @SayemAhmed I would like to have it ordered. @ nneonneo Sounds not to bad. Do you have any good tutorials? (I can google myself but it's wasted time if you know something)

Comment: Isn't there a table structure in the Framework?

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340283/datatable-equivalent-in-java) and [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1194971/dataset-class-in-java).

Comment: It seems that you've build a column-based structure. To access an entry you need to run `table.get("columnName").get(15)`. Do you need a table?

Comment: Why do want to remodel the database table in java? Use ORM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean by "better"? It depends on what do you need to do with that.

You may build

- a 2-dimensional array and a map of column names (C++ way)
- a list of objects, where each object is a row (the most Java way)
- a Guava [Table](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Table.html)

Comment: The Guava Table looks good. I already have the libary and will use it (now).